# MATLAB code requires too much time for compiling

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to compute this

[image: formula]

in MATLAB but the code requires about 8 hours to compile. In particular `e`, `Ft=[h(t);q(t)]` and `Omega` are 2x1 matrices (`e'` is 1x2), `Gamma` is a 2x2 matrix and `n=30`. Can someone help me to optimize this code?

I tried in this way:

```
aux=[0;0];
for k=0:29 
  for j=1:k-1   
    aux=[aux Gamma^j*Omega];
  end
  E(t,k+1)= e'*(sum(aux,2)+Gamma^k*[h(t);q(t)]);
end
Vix=1/30*sum(E,2);
```

EDIT

now I changed into this and it is faster, but I am not sure that I am applying correctly the formula in the picture...

```
for t=2:T
        % 1. compute today's volatility 
        csi(t) = log(SP500(t)/SP500(t-1))-r(t)+0.5*h(t);
        q(t+1) = omega+rho*q(t)+phi*((csi(t)-lambda*sqrt(h(t)))^2-h(t));
        h(t+1) = q(t)+alpha*((csi(t)-lambda*sqrt(h(t)))^2-q(t))+beta*(h(t)-q(t));
         for k=1:30
 aux=zeros(2,k);
              for j=0:k-1
            aux(:,j+1)=Gamma^j*Omega;
              end
        E(t,k)= e'*(sum(aux,2)+Gamma^k*[h(t);q(t)]);
         end
    end
Vix(2:end)=1/30*sum(E(2:end,:),2);
```

(I don't need Vix(1))

Comment: “Compile” means to translate the code to machine instructions. It takes a fraction of a second. What takes 8 hours is to **run** the code. You must include complete code if you want help (see [mre]).

Comment: Are you sure that each iteration of `k` you are intending to add to `aux`? It doesn't look right to me, since you use `sum(aux)` within that loop. I also don't understand why you build the array `aux` if all you are going to do is take its sum. Why not just add those values directly? `aux = aux + Gamma^j*Omega`?

Comment: Also, are you sure that Gamma^j is the matrix power you are currently computing? I would think it's unlikely, that the notation means something different. And you are skipping j=0 in your code as well.

Comment: `Gamma^0` is not 0. For speed you should pre-compute `Gamma^j` for all possible `j`, and re-use those same values also when you do `Gamma^k`. I bet almost all of your computation time is in this matrix power.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could post more code to see where else in it are you incurring speed penalties. I suggest that you edit your question by including the full script.

Comment: I posted more code...

Answer (score 1):

Here are some reasons I can think of:

**REPEATED COPYING(No preallocation)** The main reason for the long **run** time is the line  `aux=[aux Gamma^j*Omega]` line, in which an `array` is concatenated at every loop iteration. MATLAB's debugger should have flagged this for you in its editor and should have cited that "memory **preallocation**" using `zeros` should be implemented.

Essentially, when one concatenates arrays this way, MATLAB is internally making copies of the array at every loop iteration, thus, in addition to the math operations copying is taking place. As the array grows, the copying operations become ever more expensive. This is avoided by **preallocation**, which consists of predefining the size of the storage array (in this case the variable `aux`) so that MATLAB doesn't have to keep on allocating space on the go. Try:

```
aux = zeros(2, 406); %Creates a 2 by 406 array. I explain how I get 406 below:
p = 0; %A variable that indexes the columns of aux
for k=0:29 
  for j=1:k-1
    p = p+1; %Update column counter
    aux(:,p) = Gamma^j*Omega; % A 2x2 matrix multiplied by a 2x1 matrix yields a 2x1.
  end
  E(t,k+1)= e'*(sum(aux,2)+Gamma^k*[h(t);q(t)]);
end
Vix=1/30*sum(E,2);
```

Now, MATLAB simply overwrites the individual elements of `aux` instead of copying `aux`, and concatenating it with `Gamma^j*Omega`, and then overwriting `aux`. Essentially, the above makes MATLAB allocate space for `aux` ONCE instead of 406 times. I figured out that `aux` ends up being a 2 by 406 array for the `n=30` case in the end by running this code:

```
p = 0;
for k = 0:29
    for j = 1:k-1
        p = p + 1;
    end
end
```

To know the final size of `aux` for other values of `n` you should see if a formula for it is available (or derive your own).

**LOOPING TRANSPOSITION OF A CONSTANT?**
Next, `e'`. As you may know, `'` is the transpose operation. From your sample code, the variable `e` is not edited inside the `for` loops, yet you have the `'` operator inside the outer `for` loop. If you perform the transpose operation once outside the outer `for` loop you save yourself the expense of transposing it at every loop iteration.

**RUNNING TOTAL**
As a final note, I would suggest replacing `sum(aux,2)` with a variable that keeps a running total. This is because currently, this makes MATLAB sum over the entirety of `aux` at every loop iteration.

Hope this helps mate.